# How to deserialize an XML where element names are list-numerated?

Tags: c#, xml, deserialization

Good news everyone!
I have encountered a new problem with some tricky xml.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<response>
<osmp_txn_id>100500</osmp_txn_id>
<result>0</result>
<fields>
<field1 name="name">Ko Chu Bey</field1>
<field2 name="contract">777-1</field2>
...
<fieldN name="account">65000</fieldN>
</fields>
<comment>Result for round 1 of fight vs Pe Re Svet: 1:1</comment>
</response>
```

My problem is that built-in utility that generates xsd's ans cs's makes a different class for each `fieldX`. And because there could be `N` amount of them it becomes a pain in a very intimate place.
Is there a way to deserialize object from this XML into a class with array of `field` objects?

Comment: You'll need to take full control of the deserialization process;looks like those fields make a nice KeyValuePair. On my phone so can't really give an answer right now but I'd look into how I could implement ISerializable.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you have the XML in a string you can do this using Linq to XML and a regular expression for the name:

```
var fieldElementNameRegex = new Regex(
    "^field[0-9]+$",
    RegexOptions.IgnoreCase | RegexOptions.Compiled);

var xml = XElement.Parse(xmlString);

var fieldElements = xml
    .Descendants()
    .Where(e => fieldElementNameRegex.IsMatch(e.Name.ToString()))
    .ToArray();
```

Comment: Sorry, looks like what I've said was misunderstood. I ment, is it possible to deserialize such xml into a class with array of `field` objects.

Comment: As a possible solution, i find going with `Regex` throught response string and changing all the `fieldX` into `field` and deserialize it after replacement.

Comment: Just to clarify why you mean by 'deserialize' - you mean turn it into an object at runtime?

Comment: ...and yeah - if you have a `field` class ready for the XML to be deserialized to you could use a regex to replace the field[n] element names before deserialization...

Comment: Yes, transform xml string into object - `System.Xml.XmlSerializer.Deserialize()`

Answer (score 0):

The best solution would be to make your own `IXmlSerializable` implementation to consume the xml in question. It's going to be a hassle to do up-front, but probably will be the worth it in the long run.

As an alternative (I wouldn't recommend it too strongly), you can write a little hack to reflect on the properties of the default-serialized object - the one that you explained is being generated by the built-in utility.

For instance, assuming:

public class Field
    {
      public string name;
      public string value;
    }

```
public class response
{
  public Field field1;
  public Field field2;
  public Field field3;
  public Field field4;
  public Field field5;
  public Field field6;
  public Field field7;
  public string comments;
  public string osmp_txn_id;
  public string result;
}
```

You can define the following "convenience" class:

```
public class myResponse
{
  public string comments;
  public string osmp_txn_id;
  public string result;
  public List<Field> fields;
}
```

And this would be how to populate the more convenient class:

```
myResponse ConvertFromResult(response target)
{
  var returnObject = new myResponse();

  var fields = target.GetType().GetFields().Where(f => f.FieldType == typeof(Field));
  returnObject.fields = (from f in fields
    let fp = f.GetValue(target) as Field
    where fp != null
    select fp).ToList();

  returnObject.comments = target.comments;
  returnObject.osmp_txn_id = target.osmp_txn_id;
  returnObject.result = target.result;

  return returnObject;
}
```

This is all conceptual, so you probably would need to "roll-your-own" solution from here on.  One other alternative would be to use an extension method to return an `IEnumerable<field>` for the xml-deserialized object, which would be feasible if you're going to use it in non-performance intensive ways.

```
public static class responseExtensions
{
  private static IEnumerable<Field> GetFields(this response target)
  {
    var fields = target.GetType().GetFields().Where(f => f.FieldType == typeof(Field));
    return from f in fields
           let fp = f.GetValue(target) as Field
           where fp != null
           select fp;
  }
}
```